# Finding $θ$ such that $|a+b e^{iθ}|$ is maximized, $a$ and $b$ being complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I must find the max value of $|a+be^{iθ}|$. I already know that $|a+b e^{iθ}| \le |a| + |b| $, but I have no clue about how to find θ for it being equal...

Comment: Your title doesn't describe your question very well. In fact it has the trivial answer $\theta = 2 \pi n$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the geometry of the situation. Regard $a$ and $b$ as vectors in the plane. $be^{i\theta}$ is the vector $b$ rotated through a counterclockwise angle of $\theta$, and $a + be^{i\theta}$ is the vector sum of $a$ and $be^{i\theta}$. When is the head of that vector furthest away from the origin? Try to convince yourself that it is furthest when $a$ and $be^{i\theta}$ point in the same direction. That should help you determine what $\theta$ should be.

Comment: So, if I'm right, I get $θ = \pi - \widehat{ \vec{a},\vec {b}}$